# Python Selenium cannot click submit button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

A quick question. How do I click on the following button link using selenium in python? The button does not have any ID or value

```
<a href="/" login="" class="classname123">Login</a> == $0
```

I receive below mentioned error:

```
Unable to locate element: //input[@type="submit" and @title="login"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `driver.find_element_by_class('classname123').click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is `<a>`, not `<input>`, doesn't have `type` attribute and it has text `Login`, not title `login`

```
//a[contains(., "Login")]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. The firefox browser opens and click the button. Is this also possible at the background? (underwater) Or only by physical acces?

Comment: @Jessekraal Have a look at [headless browser](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/headless-browser-testing-selenium-webdriver/). It can be used for testing without opening actual browser (I never worked with them though).

Answer (score 2):

You can use search by link text to handle exact element:

```
login = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Login')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have shared is `<a>` and your error is in `<input>` as your `xpath` saying

use following to click on that link

```
.//a[text()='Login']
```

or

```
.//a[@class='classname123'][text()='Login']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Login')]
```

OR

Try this way using class attribute of `a` tag.

```
//a[@class='classname123']
```